# How do I write a complex regex as string in python3?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So, I've got this regex I would like to compile:

```
(?<!\\)(?:(')|")(?(1)(\\'|[^'\r])+?'|(\\"|[^\r"])+?")
```

It works fine. But because there are ' and " signs, I need to escape them. So I do:

```
re.compile('''(?<!\\)(?:(')|")(?(1)(\\'|[^'\r])+?'|(\\"|[^\r"])+?")''')
```

Which give me the 'unbalanced parenthesis' error.
I also tried:

```
re.compile('(?<!\\)(?:(\')|")(?(1)(\\\'|[^\'\r])+?\'|(\\"|[^\r"])+?")')
```

Are all those backslashes confusing it, somehow? It's hard enough to understand without having to add *more* backslashes to escape the backslashes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are. Use a raw string.

```
>>> re.compile(r'(?<!\\)(?:(\')|")(?(1)(\\\'|[^\'\r])+?\'|(\\"|[^\r"])+?")')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x242aa60>
```

Comment: Ah, that's what those little r's mean I've been seeing here and there. Thanks

Comment: It makes more sense to use a triple-quoted string (as in the original post) instead of escaping quote characters.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is not the quotes.